# como aceder através de callout bubble num mapa a descritivo numa tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sou estudante e estou a desenvolver uma app em IOS em que é fornecido ao utilizador um mapa com alguns locais assinalados (pin) em que na callout aparece o nome do local.(através de um ficheiro JSON)
Através de uma tabBar pode aceder uma tableView onde vem enunciado todos os locais e tocando num, passa para uma outra view onde é disponibilizado todo o descritivo desse local.
A minha questão é: como aceder directamente de uma callout bubble escolhida no mapa para o respectivo descritivo numa outra view?

Comment: Oi, mariana, bem vinda ao [pt.so]. É melhor se você ilustrar seu problema com o código que está a trabalhar. Você é livre para **[edit]** a pergunta e adicionar mais informações. O guia [ask] merece uma lida.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

Dá uma olhada nesse método, acho que é isso, se não poste o código pra olharmos.